# Arbitrary variable in induction

Tags: solution-verification, induction, natural-numbers

I want to prove that for any $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ that $a+b\in\mathbb{N}$, where $0\in\mathbb{N}$. Here is my attempt with induction:

We fix $b$ and induct over $a$. It is true for $a=0,$ since $b+0=b\in\mathbb{N}$. Now suppose for $a\in\mathbb{N}$ that $a+b\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $b$ is arbitrary, we can choose the integer $b+1\in\mathbb{N}$, and we know $a+(b+1)\in\mathbb{N}$ by hypothesis. From this we know $(a+1)+b\in\mathbb{N}$, so the statement is true for $a+1$ as well. Therefore, it is true for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

I don't like how I justify choosing $b+1$ to add to $a$. I can't say "choose $b=b+1$", but I'm not sure I can use a different variable name either, since I'm relying on $a+b\in\mathbb{N}\implies a+b+1\in\mathbb{N}$, with the same variable names. How can I write this proof better?

Comment: You are right to be worried about how you justified choosing $b+1$. You are assuming that if $b\in \Bbb N$, then so is $b+1$, which is part of what you are supposed to be proving. There is no way around this in your argument here. You need to first prove that for all $n \in \Bbb N$, that $n+1$ is also in $\Bbb N$. And that has to come from your definition of $\Bbb N$ and/or $+$. Once to have that, $a+b \in \Bbb N$ and associativity of $+$ are sufficient to show $(a+1) + b \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: But has it been proven that addition is associative yet? If you haven't proven that, you cannot use it to prove that addition is closed on $\Bbb N$. In you proof so far, you haven't made any real use of the defining properties of $\Bbb N$ or $+$, You cannot prove this without them. And we don't know exactly which of the many possible definitions of $\Bbb N$ you are using.